# Distribution Transaction Completed - Error - SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Trying to execute a stored procedure to update a certain data warehouse, however when I execute the stored procedure I get an error message stating:

> error Msg 8525, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Distributed transaction
>   completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL
>   transaction

After some Googling, it suggested to configure DTC settings, but I have already checked my MSDTC and it is already checked for allowing inbound and outbound for Transaction Manager Communication.

Any ideas to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it was a deadlock - rebooted the server and issue was resolved.